# Outer Join and then calculating the counts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join, case, outer-join

I'm trying to calculate counts of relationship based on where conditions with help of `CASE` statement in my Laravel application.

I've a `Project` Model which has `ManyToMany` relationship with `Professional` Model. I've multiple where conditions to filter projects data. I need to calculated project count where I've verified professionals and reverse. I achieved this by following below query in my controller:

```
$projects = Project::wherehas('professionals',function ($q){
        $q->where('professionals.contact_verified', 1);
        $q->where('professionals.professional_active', 1);
    })->get();
    
    return response()->json(['data' => collect([
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Yes'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'No']
    ])->map(function ($item) use($projects) {
        if ($item['name'] == 'Yes')
            $item['projects_count'] =  Project::whereHas('professionals', function ($q) {
                $q->where('professionals.contact_verified', 1);
                $q->where('professionals.professional_active', 1);
            })->count();
        if ($item['name'] == 'No')
            $item['projects_count'] = Project::whereHas('professionals', function ($q) use($projects){
                $q->whereNotIn('project_professional.project_id',collect($projects)->pluck('id'));
            })->count();
        return $item;
    })], 200);
```

I want to optimise query and achieve with `CASE` statement, I tried below:

```
Project::where(// some condtions)
    ->leftJoin('project_professional', 'projects.id', 'project_professional.project_id')
    ->join('professionals', 'project_professional.professional_id', 'professionals.id')
    ->select(
        DB::Raw('COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN professionals.contact_verified = 1 AND professionals.professional_active = 1 THEN projects.id END) AS "Yes"'),
        //want to count reverse of above condition
    )
    ->first();
```

How to get data for `No` section?

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.